# How to get nested data in Gmail API and JSON with Python

Tags: python, json, gmail-api

I'm having trouble accessing nested values and keys in Gmail's API for Python.  I'm getting close but I don't know how to access the values of this.  How do I extract the data from the 'Subject' and the "From" sections.

```py
        for message in messages:
            msg = service.users().messages().get(userId='me', id=message['id']).execute()
            subject = msg['payload']['headers']
            for values in subject:
                name = values['name'] #This only prints the values "From" and "Subject" by itself not with the actual subject.
                print(values)
                print("\n")
```

The print(values) returns the following json data (there's dozens more lines and it's not always the same count so I'm not sure a hard coded integer will help.

```
{'name': 'From', 'value': 'Duolingo <hello@duolingo.com>'}
{'name': 'Subject', 'value': ' Your weekly progress report'}
```

How do I get just the data to the right of "value" in both of these?  For example, "Your weekly progress report"?

Comment: Are you just asking how to use dictionaries?

Comment: I knew the basics, but not how to dig deeper into a dictionary.  Someone answered it below though.  Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Adding a variable
`value = values['value']`
should give you the value from that output

It looks like what you have labelled subject is actually a combination of subject,  who it's from and by the sounds of it other data so I might change that variable to email_data

so the resulting code would be

```
for values in email_data:
  name = values['name']
  value = values['value']

  print(values)
  print("\n")
```

Comment: Yes, that was it!  Thank you so much.  Now I need the for loop to find the from and subject and the corresponding data to it.